# Best way to designate unit of weight in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am working with a simple database with tables of `users`, `products` and `orders`, but previously the `products` table was not very well designed in my opinion in that for the `weights` column, it just had a number, but its unclear whether its in pounds or ounces.

I have tried to find documentation on how to designate pounds and ounces as a unit of weight for a table, but I have not been successful. Can anyone suggest a way to do this? Again the column is simply called `weight`, how do I make it clear that it starts at 2 ounces up to 1 pound as a unit of weight inside of Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct is to use the metric system, but if you have to use imperial measurements, I suggest that you store the weights as ounces but have [`Computed` | `Calculated` | `Virtual` | `Derived`] columns - actually called `Generated` in PostgreSQL - see this wiki article about [`Virtual columns`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_column) - which says that the "The industry standard" is:

```
column_name [type] GENERATED ALWAYS AS (expression)
```

PostgreSQL is normally very good about sticking to the SQL standard! The PostgreSQL documentation on generated columns is available [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html).

### Imperial units - i.e. weight in ounces (see below for metric):

I would have something like this (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b3067b84517cd1c6c91c6a0d9b9e8e2c)):

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  field_1 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  field_2 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  --
  --  Other fields
  -- 
  weight_oz INTEGER NOT NULL,
  pound_oz INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (weight_oz/16) STORED,   -- INTEGER division
  ounce_oz INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MOD(weight_oz, 16)) STORED  -- Remainder
);
```

And then populate it with some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO foo (field_2, weight_oz) VALUES ('asdfa', 25), ('adfads', 78);
```

And then:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Result:

```
field_1 field_2  weight_oz  pound_oz    ounce_oz
      1   asdfa         25         1           9
      2  adfads         78         4          14
```

Now, unfortunately, PostgreSQL doesn't yet have the `VIRTUAL` keyword for the storage type of the generated field (unlike, say, MySQL) which would be better here, but AIUI, it's on the way.

Also, you didn't mention your version of PostgreSQL (you should **always** do this), but methods to do this in versions prior to 12 are explored [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/470530).

### S.I. (Système International) units - i.e. weight in kg.

I've added a method for dealing where the weight is stored in kg (S.I. units are the ideal storage medium for any quantity IMHO). From [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/weight/kg-to-ounce.html), "1 kg = 35.27396195 oz". Conversely, the mass m in ounces (oz) is equal to the mass m in kilograms (kg) divided by 0.02834952 (the reciprocal of 35.xxx).

From the PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html), a `REAL` variable:

> On most platforms, the real type has a range of at least 1E-37 to
> 1E+37 with a precision of at least 6 decimal digits.

That should be sufficient for most needs - if not, you could use `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` types, but (from the same page):

> However, calculations on numeric values are very slow compared to the
> integer types, or to the floating-point types

This method works to the nearest ounce - I've tested [here](https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/conversions/common/kg-to-pounds-ounces.php) and it appears to work well. Of course, if you want fractional ounces to eliminate potential rounding errors, just keep it `REAL` (pardon the pun!)! A fiddle is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4afbd5863ea852600695a267ae846ee3):

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  field_1 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  field_2 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  --
  --  Other fields
  -- 
  weight_kg REAL NOT NULL,
  pound_kg INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((weight_kg * 35.273961)::INT)/16) STORED, 
  ounce_kg INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MOD((weight_kg * 35.273961)::INT, 16)) STORED
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO foo (field_2, weight_kg) 
VALUES 
('xxxxx', 0.85), ('asdfa', 25), ('adfads', 78);
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Result:

```
field_1 field_2 weight_kg   pound_kg    ounce_kg
      1   xxxxx      0.85          1          14
      2   asdfa        25         55           2
      3   adfads       78        171          15
```

Comment: This is a great solution.  If you have a requirement to preserve the original values, you can add a units column.  You can implement a function that converts values to any desired units. Not ideal.

Comment: @JimD - you might like to upvote it so! :-) There are a plethora of potential problems with these unit conversions which only surface when one starts looking in detail at them - thankfully pounds and ounces are the same on both sides of the Atlantic! But then things get tricky - do you have `stone` (not really used in the US). Short or long ton? Various professions have different weight/length/volume measurements for historical reasons. This is why my **personal** choice would be to store everything in SI and then convert to yards, fathoms, furlongs, chains...

Comment: Working once in the UK for a rail company, they actually used furlongs and chains and the like - I was appalled. Having lived in France, I find the metric system to be beautifully elegant and simple and decimally based! Why anyone would want to use another system is beyond me - even in the US, the medical profession has been metricised - but it'll be a cold day in hell before the whole country makes the change!

Comment: I upvoted the answer. I agree units are often messy and storing data in consistent units is often the optimum solution. I have to deal with databases that must store the data as originally provided and has data going back to the 1940s.

Comment: Do your databases store currency as [groats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groat_(coin))? Volumes as [firkins and hogsheads](https://scotchaddict.com/scotch-barrel-sizes-firkin-kilderkin-hogshead-butt-tun.html) - though I kind of like the idea of the **butt** as a unit of volume :-) (check link). Reading about the different professions and punishments for transgressions, up to and including impaling is great. Good impalers could keep their subjects alive for > 24hrs-Ouch! Thanks for upvote! **"storing data in consistent units is often the optimum solution"** - base units as SI -only way to go!